# Longitudinal regression for categorical data (possibly in R)

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, categorical-data

Suppose I have a categorical outcome variable (`stand`) from students' reading performance that is like: `"Notapproach"`, `"Approaches"`, `"Meets"`, `"Masters"`.

As we read from left to right, the categories increase in strength. What kind of regression can I use to analyze such data longitudinally in `R`?

Here is the data (regression formula: `stand ~ year * group`):

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/readlong.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a natural order to the levels of the outcome, but the difference between the levels is unknown, it is an ordinal variable so you could use a GLMM for ordinal responses such as a cumulative link mixed model (See the `ordinal` package in R as an example)